# Kubernetes - Windows container on Azure container service issues with azure file persistent volume mount

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-container

I have deployed a Docker container in Azure Container Services using Kubernetes.

I have 3 containers defined in my service, one of the containers requires Persistent Volume so I have followed all the instruction to use azure file as persistent volume mount but it does not work.

The same volume works in linux cluster but for windows cluster I see that the folder gets mounted in the windows container but I don't see any files which were pre-loaded in the fileshare.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

I am running similar kind of setup with windows containers under Azure ACS kubernetes and facing issues while attaching my volume(azure file share ) to container under deployment file.

Have you resolved this issue. below is my deployment file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
   name: azure-secret
 type: Opaque
 data:
   azurestorageaccountname: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   azurestorageaccountkey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 ---  
 apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
   kind: Deployment
 metadata:
  name: name1
 spec:
   replicas: 1
  template:
   metadata:
      labels:
        app: name1
    spec:
       containers:
      - name: name1
        image: acr.azurecr.io/myrepo:v3
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 80
          name: name1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: azure
          mountPath: D:\  
      volumes:
      - name: azure
        azureFile:
          secretName: azure-secret
          shareName: aksshare
          readOnly: false    
---
 apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: name1
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: name1
```

post #kubectl create -f

all got created well . but when I am doing #kubectl describe pods

it is giving me long error full of page saying. container encounter en error during createcontainer:failure in windows system call:the peram,eter is incorrect. and lon long error logs.

If you have resolved you can share your process and deployment file.

Thanks,

Comment: I did not get any error during pod creation but the mounted folder did not have any content which I already uploaded. Did you try changing the mount path from D: to /foldername?

My issue is not resolved yet so I am assuming it is not supported yet in windows container.